# Yesod Esqueleto isJust

Tags: haskell, yesod, esqueleto

I've been using `isNothing`, from `Esqueleto`, but now I would like to just test if it is `not null`, I've noticed that there is no `isJust`, I would like to know the reason it doesn't exist, and what could I do to achieve similar effect: `isJust (a ^. MyEntityMyField)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you define it yourself?

```
isJust = not_ . isNothing
```

Comment: It seems like the library should define it. Maybe open an issue @FtheBuilder?

Comment: @MaxGabriel I will open

Comment: @Daniel Martin I've defined it myself, I posted just to help others with similar problems...